# Excel formula to show linked cell ID

Tags: excel, reference, pointers, cell, formula

In an excel cell, I've placed a simple formula

```
=C4
```

The cell typically displays the **value** of cell C4, but instead I want to see the linked cell **ID** instead, which in this case is "C4".

Is there a formula to show me this? like:

```
=SHOWCELL(C4)
```

The reason I need this instead of simply typing the value of "C4" into the cell, is so Excel will **maintain** the link to the correct cell even if rows are inserted/deleted, AND show me which cell is linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`Cell`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cell.php) function.

> In Excel, the **Cell** function can be used to retrieve information about a cell. This can include contents, formatting, size, etc.

```
=Cell("address", C4)
```

This displays `$C$4`.

When inserting a row before `C4`, it is changed to `$C$5`.

---

In case you do not want the `$` signs, one way would be the [`Substitute`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/substitute.php) function:

```
=Substitute( Cell("address", C4), "$", "" )
```

Comment: Note that the return value is an absolute address (`$C$4`).

Comment: @KennyTM: Right :) I was just extending my answer when you posted your comment, and now I edited it again to provide a solution using `Substitute`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own User Defined Function to achieve this. I call it "CellReference".

Usage:

```
=CellReference(B6)
```

displays "B6"

To use it, launch VBA, insert a module, and then copy the below into the module:

```
Function CellReference(cell As range) As String

     CellReference = cell.Address(0, 0, xlA1)

End Function
```